# Doctrine2 Paginator, getArrayResult

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I'm dealing with a fairly complex querybuilder (in a repository function), which is using a lot of things like `partial c.{id,name,created}` and a bunch of fetchjoins to try and keep both the amount of data and the amount of queries down.

This is however not enough, but the front end representation is paged anyway, so I'd like to make some ajax calls to fetch data when needed.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
  ->select('a whole bunch')
  ->join('many joins')
  ->setFirstResult(0)
  ->setMaxResults(10)
```

The above method [doesn't work for complex joins](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only), I do `setMaxResults(10)` and get 2 results, and `setMaxResults(1000)` gets me 118 results. Doctrine advises to use their [Pagination](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) class, as it will handle the count/iteration properly.

Now that works all fine if I loop over the Iterator object provided by `new Paginator($query, true)`, but the code calling the repository function expects to get an Array from `getArrayResult`.

The iterator contains full entity objects, which means I would have to rewrite all the services to use methods instead of array keys.

Is there a way to use the Paginator with an ArrayResult?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `Hydration Mode` to your query.

```
//Set query hydration mode
$query->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```